# Передача RTSP/RTP видеопотока на сайт

Tags: веб-программирование, видео

Приветствую.
Кто нибудь сталкивался с сабжем? Требуется транслировать потоковое видео с ip-камеры на сайт. Как проще всего реализовать?

Это реализуется напрямую или, может быть, нужно ставить промежуточный сервер, который бы, например, конвертировал RTP-поток в flv-файлы, которые бы и проигрывались на сайте?

Comment: Не приходилось сталкиваться. Насколько мне известно, flash умеет воспроизводить поток RTP. Однако если клиентов много, то скорее всего придётся сделать несколько ретрансляторов просто чтобы всё это не завалилось под нагрузкой.

Comment: Все flash-плееры, которые нашел, могли воспроизводить только потоки RTMP, не RTSP.
Похоже для того, чтобы выводить во флэше, нужно сначала конвертировать потоки на сервере.

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно в качестве промежуточнго взять например, [VideoLan](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch04.html).
Потом с него и берете src для html-a.

А у вас какая камера ? MJPEG поддерживает ?

**UPD**

еще можно в виде(пример) `<img src="ваш_ip_camera:port/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=test">` вставить на сайт, преимущество в том что **без каких либо компонентов - плееров**, чисто хтмл-е вещает, я сам использую такой код, ну качество не лучше чем Н.264, но штук 10-15 соединений обслуживает.
Удачи!

Comment: вот такая:
http://www.pro-ipcamera.ru/catalog/ip-kamera-etrovision-ev8781a-cl.html
да, MJPEG поддерживает. 
Разобрался, для одной камеры и небольшого числа клиентов сервер не нужен, стандартный media player встраиваемый все показывает (правда наверное только на виндовой платформе).
Еще можно использовать silverlight.
Но у меня предполагается 6-10 камер и посещаемость, все равно сервер нужен будет.

Answer (score 1):

Транслировать RTP поток на сайт можно с помощью WebRTC. С одной стороны передаются данные по протоколу RTP, с другой используется [Media Source Api](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/).

Есть статья (англ.) http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/11/Stream-video-using-the-MediaSource-API и пример http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/media-source.html

И еще одна по теме http://habrahabr.ru/post/229243/